# What is the need of NullCipher

Tags: java, cryptography

Ciphers in JAVA are used to get the cipher text for a given plain text. With that said what is the real need of the javax.crypto.NullCipher.

As per the [Oracle Docs],(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/NullCipher.html) The NullCipher class is a class that provides an "identity cipher" -- one that does not transform the plain text. As a consequence, the ciphertext is identical to the plaintext.

Then just wanted to understand what is the real need of the NullCipher class and what are its use cases?

Comment: It can be used for testing, when what you're testing is not the encryption, but some other logic around the code that does encryption.

Comment: It serves largely the same function as `Function.identity()`: it's a thing you can pass where a thing is required by an API, but you don't want that thing to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullCipher` is indeed useful for testing. It could for instance be used for implementing the `TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA` cipher suite, which has a similar purpose. So you'd leave all the code there - including IV generation, `Cipher` instances and so forth, but simply switch off encryption & confidentiality, leaving the rest - record parsing, handshake, entity authentication & message integrity - intact.

Transmission or intermediate encoding / decoding errors can be detected that way. If the plaintext doesn't survive with the `NullCipher`, then the problem is clearly not with the decryption. Beware though that the block size of 1 byte may hide errors for ciphers where the block size is 8 bytes (3DES) or 16 bytes (AES). In other word, `NullCipher` acts as a stream cipher. This is not that surprising: it simply returns the plaintext after all - no blocks are required.

Care should be taken that such functionality is removed, is disabled or at the very least isn't enabled by default for non-debug builds. Note                             that `NullCipher` will still create a copy of the data. I would therefore **not** use it to implement a choice between encrypting / not encrypting in release builds.